# How do I use the meslo font for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened the integrated terminal on ***visual studio code*** and I did not like the editor font value that it defaults to. I want to change it to `Meslo Regular Z Powerline`.
Here is the gist: when I entered this value `"Meslo Regular Z Powerline"`, it turns out that visual studio code does not recognize it. I think the issue is because of the space characters it contains. I have it installed on my Mac but it is still not recognizing it.
What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Since the font name contains spaces, try surrounding it with single quotes: `"'Meslo Regular Z Powerline'"` or escaped double quotes: `"\"Meslo Regular Z Powerline\""`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have seen that the name I was using is not the correct name: Here is the correct name here
***"Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline"***

```
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline"
```

This one worked fine

Comment: Pay close attention to the name of your font file. In my case the Meslo font was named "Meslo LG M for Powerline" which resulted in a serif font in the integrated terminal with a warning message from VS Code "The terminal only supports monospace fonts."

Answer (score 85):

None of these answers were working for me because I was using MesloLGS NF for my iTerm2. What I did was took the exact value that was being displayed in iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Text under the font section,

[image: iTerm2 Settings]

and typed that into my settings.json under terminal.integrated.fontfamily.

[image: VS Code Settings]

Copy from here:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF",
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as your VS code editor font should match what's working in terminal

Comment: Make your config copy-n-paste-able ;)

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I have to put `MesloLGS NF, Regular`.

[image]

On Manjaro GNOME Terminal.

Comment: This did the trick for me using VSCode + ZSH + Powerlevel 10K

Comment: This same font name works on Windows, with added single-quote: `'MesloLGS NF'`

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 18.04 none of the stuff in the answers worked for me, it kept complaining about with the message:

> The terminal only supports monospace fonts.

So I dig a bit and this is my solution:

No need to add extra fonts in Ubuntu 18.04 to fix this, we just need to add the missing powerline fonts inside vscode to display the symbols correctly.

So I just added to my settings:

```
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace, PowerlineSymbols",
    ...
}
```

And everything was nice and smooth and I could see my VSCode terminal with powerline just like the regular OS terminal.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

**With Vscode terminal in Ubuntu :  * Only In Ubuntu**

If you are using **font-awesome** icons as well in terminal

```
{
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline', 'fontawesome'",
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 15
```

}

Below is my vscode terminal

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Mac** users version:

```
"terminal.external.linuxExec": "iterm",
"terminal.external.osxExec": "Iterm.app",
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline",
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the following font from here

https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/Meslo%20Dotted/Meslo%20LG%20M%20DZ%20Regular%20for%20Powerline.ttf

Open settings in `vs code`

```
>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
```

Add the following line in `settings.json`

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline"
```

Answer (score 3):

As I am using OhMyZsh with powerLevel10k in Linux mint, I had to configure my zsh shell with the `MesloLGS NF Regular` font.

[image: Screenshot for terminal preferences]

But my VS Code terminal still did not support the font and icons of the
powerlevel10k theme.

After hours of trial and error, I just figured out it should be
`MesloLGS NF` instead of `MesloLGS NF Regular`.

1. Go to VS Code settings
2. Search for `terminal.font`
3. Under `Terminal > Integrated: Font Family`, paste this: `MesloLGS NF`

[image: My VScode settings and terminal looks like this now]

Comment: For me, i missed those quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

Just locate your Meslo*.ttf file from which you installed the font, and check the actual name of font in system installer:
[image]
Then copy that name to vscode settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setting for fish terminal inside vcode with Powerline

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline",
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/fish",
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/local/bin/fish",
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fix for iTerm2 and VS Code 1.41.1

Copy the exact Font from your iTerm2 settings (iTerm2/Preferences/Profiles/Text)
In my case the font was "Meslo LG M for Powerline"

Then in VS code font settings (Code/Preferences/Settings/Text Editor/Font)
Add the font to font family.

Font family for me was initially set to: "Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace"
Just add your iTerm font to the end like so:

"Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace, Meslo LG M for Powerline"

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.. finally found it with:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'MesloLGS NF', Courier, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace"
```

Left in the other fonts as example on how to chain them.